# Can I refrigerate the stuff left over on the baking sheet?

Tags: baking

I made some--delicious--dinner rolls and decided to put the rest in fridge. Is it safe to put the leftover along with the baking sheet in the fridge? Not sure what material the baking sheet is made of, non-stick carbon steel I believe.

Comment: Did I reas your comment below correctly? Your rolls are *filled*? If so, with what kind of filling? This *may* mean storing at room temperature isn't safe. Please clarify, you can just [edit] your post.

Comment: Yes, I have eggs, spinach, bacon, ham, cheese, and other seasonings. I am not trying to store them at room temperature. It's why I am trying to put them in fridge

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it'd be safe to put the sheet in the fridge. But you might not want to if they're just plain rolls:

- Refrigeration makes bread go stale faster, so you may not want to refrigerate your rolls at all.
- It's important to get things airtight in the fridge, and often it's a pain to wrap up a baking sheet to be airtight.
- If the coating on the sheet isn't perfect, and it collects condensation in the fridge, it might rust a little faster.
- Baking sheets can be bulky and awkward in the fridge.

If you want to keep bread long enough that room temperature storage doesn't work well (more than a few days), the freezer is a better option.

On the other hand, if they're filled with something perishable, you'd need to refrigerate or freeze. In that case, you could use the sheet if you really have to and can wrap it reasonably airtight, but generally it'd still be easier to transfer to a bag or smaller container.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you've let it cool, yes. You want to avoid putting hot things in the fridge, since it risks raising the temperature into the danger zone. It won't react or do anything bad.

Though I can't imagine why you'd want to. It will take up a lot of room. Why not just take them off the sheet and into a plastic bag or other container?

For that matter... dinner rolls will be just fine at room temperature for a day or two. Better, in fact; they tend to get [stale faster in the refrigerator](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2011/08/bread-goes-stale-about-six-times-faster-in-the-refrigerator-than-at-room-temperature/).

Comment: all the goodies fall out when I take the rolls out of baking sheet xd